# Monodevelop use of Winforms

Tags: winforms, macos, cross-platform, monodevelop

I was looking around the MonoDevelop projects and noticed a reference to the Windows.Forms namespace. I belive it was using the Openfile dialog. (I should say I was on a Windows machine.) I was wondering how this works when MD is run on a Mac or Linux box?

Is the project/module that reference the Windows.Forms namespace only load on Windows desktops?  Does Mono support the Winforms namespace? It would seem to me that Winforms eventually resovles to native API calls which wouldn't work on other OSs.

The reason I'm asking is because I want to develop a cross-platform application and I was looking at MonoDevelop to see how it handles things. I know Gtk is the clear choice, so I was surprised to see the Windows.forms reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms

And from their FAQ (http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Winforms):

> What are you using to implement Windows.Forms?
>   Windows.Forms is implemented fully in C# managed code and uses System.Drawing to perform most of its tasks.
>
> For more details see the Winforms Roadmap
>
> A small driver is required for each operating system supported. Currently we have drivers for:
>
> - X Window System
> - Win32 Window System
> - Mac OSX Window System

Comment: <hanging his head in shame> Opps. Sorry I missed that. Either that or I read it when i should have been sleeping and just totally misssed it. Thanks.